# Render not showing UV texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

I have added a texture to a cube in the UV editor and it shows up fine in textured view [image]

But when I render it there is no texture
[image]

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to add a material to your mesh to have it show in the render. Also, after adding a material, go to the *Properties panel > Textures tab* and add the texture. Don't forget to assign the UV map in *Textures tab > Mapping dropdown*.

See this screenshot for more details:

[image]

Comment: Woah, these are a little hard to find for a newb like me, Thanks for the attached screenshot! I am yet a bit confused on to how the properties menu items relate to one another. Materials seems to be a parent for texture or can be at some rate.

Comment: yes, material is parent of texture.
But in texture panel, 3 items are shown. first is world, material and text/brush.
when you want to add texture to material, make sure, material is selectd, not world or texture.

Comment: **For Cycles or Eevee** please check the other answer

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer applies to the soon discontinued "Blender Internal" renderer and has become obsolete. The concept however stays the same:

---

**A texture, by itself, is just "information": an image whose coordinates are mapped to the surface of a 3D object.**

This doesn't only apply to images representing the diffuse color of the object. A texture could be many things: color-coded density of hair, normal maps, bump maps, mixing factor between materials. The Texture view (removed in 2.80) or *Texture Paint* mode is used to display such textures as plain colors, whether or not they *are* supposed to be colors.

**To become color, *i.e.* to be used by the renderer, the texture must be part of a *Material* specification.**

---

Since the adoption of **Cycles** and **Eevee**, the material specification is done using Nodes. The most basic use of a Texture is to determine the "Color" of a BSDF Shader Node. Explained below.

#### How to use a texture as the object's material color

1. In the *Material* tab, if not enabled, hit <kbd>Use Nodes</kbd>. A *Diffuse* (pre-2.79) or *Principled* (post-2.79) shader will appear.
2. Use the little "o" button next to "*Color*" and insert a "*Image Texture*"

   Select the desired image with the little Image icon
3. (*optional*) Select "*Texture Coordinate > UV*" for the "*Vector*" input

[image]

---

(P.S. this corresponds to creating this node setup in the *Node/Shader Editor*:

[image]
)

Comment: There is no "use nodes" under Surface anymore (I'm using 3.6.4).