# Texture view works, but render is without texture

Tags: rendering, uv

I have this bogie:

[image]

It's textured with UV Map in a dark grey as you can see in texture view. However when rendering, it's nicely rendered, but no texture is to be seen:

[image]

I checked this question/answer already: [Render not showing UV texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/render-not-showing-uv-texture)

EDIT:
I did all the steps mentioned in various tutorials and in the Blender wiki:

I added a material, then a texture. I created seams, unwrapped my mesh, saved the UV layout, changed its colour to dark grey and assigned the image back to the texture. In texture view you can see the result:

The frame is just plain dark grey, the wheel set has a light grey tread.

In render view it's just the default untextured grey.

Frame and wheels are different objects with different Materials, different Textures and different texture images.

Here is the [blend](http://stuff.nylle.de/270-tmp_stackexchange.blend).

Comment: In the lower right corner, where it says Map:, try selecting the UV map and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes I tried that - no difference.

Comment: Do you have right image with texture? Does your texture influence color? It is wise to drop your blend file somewhere (e.g.: Dropbox, Google Drive).

Comment: I tried it myself, just after I posted my comment, and I realised that it made no difference. You should probably post your .blend at http://pasteall.org/blend and put the link in your question.

Comment: I looked at it and fiddled a little, and it appears that the texture is only applied to a very small part of one wheel. And honestly, this is for someone with more experience than I have. It's probably a simple thing, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the setting of render layers. You have selected material that overwrites all materials. Remove this material and it will work.

[image: Setting of render layers]

Comment: I found this seemingly unused Material in the Outliner under Render Layer and wondered what this is for. I tried to remove it without success. So this is how to remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem while trying to render a simple banana.
I used UV map for texturing and material and
Texture Paint manually for adding some tones of brown.
Everything looked great except when rendered.
After having tried everything possible, I discovered this:
While in 3d view:
- On the top left of the screen there's a menu item called RENDER (next to FILE)
- Select OpenGL render image.
My image was rendered in no time and perfect!
You might want to give it a try if you experience the same problem I had.