# OBJ file imported renders without texture

Tags: texturing, import

I posted this question:
[Imported 3D scan displays texture in editor, but renders without texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23255/imported-3d-scan-displays-texture-in-editor-but-renders-without-texture)
and wasn't able to figure out my issue with the answers I was given and cannot find anyone else asking anything similar, so I imagine it's something quite simple that I'm just missing.

The issue I am having is that I am trying to use blender to reduce the filesize of a 3D model in obj mtl format to export it to three.js in json format, however whenever I export or render it, it exports and renders without the texture and I have narrowed it down to the fact that I have not assigned the model a material and texture within blender.  I do not have the texture, as importing the obj mtl files constructs the texture from a separate format, so from my understanding the texture is entirely encapsulated within blender and is displayed perfectly well in the editor, but during the render it is not there, presumably because I can't give it a material and texture.

Am I missing something obvious here?  Is there a way to construct a texture file from what I currently have?  Sorry if posting two questions is not appropriate etiquette, but I feel as though I understand the issue more now and the nature of the question has changed.

EDIT:  I will try editing here to fully explain what I believe the problem is with the answer I was given.  When I was given the scan, I was given 3 files.  I have a .obj file, a .mtl file and a .png file that contains the texture.  However, the mapping of the texture in the .png file relies entirely on the obj and mtl files to construct it.  If I map the png file directly onto the mesh, this is what happens:

[image: 1]

However, the texture is correctly constructed within the blender environment.  I need to find a way to attach the texture as it is displayed in the editor to the mesh so that it is displayed in the render using the texture that was constructed by blender when I imported it.

It is not simply an issue of not applying the texture to the material, but rather that I don't have a texture to apply to the material, but blender does.

Comment: If you have new information, add it to the first question that was asked. The 2 questions sounded too similar to me.

Comment: I did add the additional information to the other question, but it seemed to be dead as soon as it was marked as a duplicate.  The answer given does not address my problem, however, and now I realize that it's more related to importing than texturing.

Comment: It would appear to be a mapping issue . . . you say that data is in the .obj and .mtl files?

Comment: Yes - I'm using blender's built in importer to import the obj mtl files