# Imported .obj - textures gone

Tags: export, import

I have created a 3D Model in Cinema 4D and exported it to .obj (and a .mtl-file) with Riptide Pro.

When I import it in Blender (2.74) I cannot see the textures or materials. They are visible in the scene browser (Scrennshot) but not on the object. They also don't appear when I switch to other viewport shaders.

I want to export the model to a .JSON-Object for displaying it with webGL in a browser.

What can I do to make the textures and materials appear?

[image]

Comment: The menu item where it says 'Object mode', beside that change the white sphere to the chequered sphere, to show textures. Right now you are just showing plain solid shading. Does that work for you?

Comment: or possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23255/imported-3d-scan-displays-texture-in-editor-but-renders-without-texture

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, as I have written above I tried different viewport shaders. Also the exported .JSON file does not contain a valid texture.

Comment: When you have the image viewer open, and have the object in edit mode does it show the UV + right texture? else you must manually pick the texture

Comment: make a throwaway object that you are comfortable sharing so we can test the obj + mtl+ texture import for ourselves.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-image-not-working-properly/24024#24024

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely that the view mode of 3d viewport is set to solid shading, and should be set to *Textured* shading instead.

[image]

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, as I have written above I tried different viewport shaders. Also the exported .JSON file does not contain a valid texture.

Comment: @user980018 i see, well perhaps you might share the obj + mtl + texture and we can have a better look at it, there's little reason why the obj wouldn't load correctly, unless the exporter has a quirky way of writing obj files..or something, it's difficult to say from a distance