# Why is Texture not showing after rendering

Tags: texturing

Why is texture not show after rendering. It doesn't show in the texture mode (shift +Z) [image][image]

Comment: Unwrap your object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render not showing UV texture](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/render-not-showing-uv-texture)

Comment: Am using a default texture, not a uv. Musgrave to be precise.  Do I have to always unwrap every time I want to apply texture on an object? Even a plane mesh. Can't I just apply directly to the surface of the obj

Comment: Except for procedural textures you most often have to unwrap, unless its a simple geometry, or basic generated texture coordinates suffice, like *Object* or *Generated* UVs. If that is a procedural texture then check its scale, it might be either too small or too big.