# Rendering of the imported .ply does not show textures

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, import

I have a .ply file that I obtained from a 3D scan.  In textures view, I can see the textures but when I render it I cannot see the textures.

I think I have to add a material and a texture, but I cannot seem to get the colors from the scan I took. Any help?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/render-not-showing-uv-texture  I saw this, and tried to duplicate the settings, but again I am not sure how to get the texture of my scan onto the material.

Comment: What you saw in 3D view was the vertex color. Rendering needs materials or texture to be assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Select the object of the imported model.
In the properties editor, go to the Material tab and add a new material.
For the new material, under Options, enable "Vertex Color Paint" checkbox.
Now the colors of the model should show in rendering.
[image]

Comment: It seems this option is gone in newer (2.8+?) versions