# UV Unwrapping pear

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to UV unwrap a pear shape object I modeled with an image of a pear. I just want a semi-accurate projection of the image onto the object (Not trying to make this look lifelike). The unwrap mode "project from view" seemed the closest to the image in terms of shape, but the texture is not showing up at all on the object.

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better, easier way to do a sort of image projection onto the object?
[image: UV Unwrapping Pear]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render not showing UV texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/render-not-showing-uv-texture)

Comment: That texture needs to be applied in a material and be selected to display I believe

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos That question/answer only addresses the internal render engine. This question is about cycles. Therefore the answer will not be helpful to this user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work through a camera view that is set to use the same render pixels as your reference image texture, and unwrap 'Project From View' through the camera view. Then your texture will align correctly to the uv projection, and if you plug that image into your material then it will show when in Texture view.[image] If you don't want to do that, you can set up Proportional Edit with the O key in the Uv editor and select single verts and drag them around to match the boundary of your pear image manually. Mistake I see in your picture is that you have the node window set to Compositor,and not Material and I cannot see if you already mention the image as a texture in your material to tell.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is where I am at right now: https://imgur.com/a/W6Nkk       I am trying to adjust the verts around the pear boundary manually. Is there a way to move multiple verts at the same time? It seems that I can only move one by one.

Comment: "Proportional Edit with the O key in the Uv editor and select single verts and drag them around to match the boundary of your pear image manually"

Comment: When you use Proportional Edit, you select a single vert and the influence falloff can be adjusted with mmb to affect multiple vertex around the selection.