# Texture showing up white even though I have a texture in the UV Image editor

Tags: texturing, materials

So the texture was showing up normally until I selected all of the faces that I texture painted on and then went into Texture Paint mode.

https://gyazo.com/86cc203ccd86363c52c6552e30369f24

Now It's showing up white even though I had textured it.

Also, please specify where any tabs and crap are located, cause I don't know that stuff quite yet.
I did not render anything. It doesn't show up in the views and probably not in the render either. This isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render not showing UV texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/render-not-showing-uv-texture)

Comment: Except mine doesn't show up in the texture paint/object mode either.