# Image Texture Not Appearing On One of Two Objects Eevee 2.8

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, roughness

[image]

Here I have a stump Object and above it a Test Plane. Both Objects have exact same Material applied via nodes. Eventually I will use the texture to control the Roughness node in the Principled BSDF, I have it attached to Color to visualize the values.

So my question is what could be preventing my Texture from appearing on my Stump but appear just fine on the Test Plane with the exact same Material applied?

Here is an image of my Node setup for the Material.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render not showing UV texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/render-not-showing-uv-texture)

Comment: What are your UV's? Your material is using your UVmap.